# Logic Not Working After Moving to Service Layer in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some functionality in my Angular 2 app that I'd like to move to a service layer, because currently several components use the exact same functionality (and thus code is repeated). Thus far, however, I'm having trouble getting the functionality to work when I move it to the service layer. It does work as is when called directly from the component layer.

First, here's the functionality in my component. Basically I'm taking in some filter choices made by the user, and then filtering my observable call based on these filter selections:

```
body: any = {'group': 'consulting'};

private processType(name: string, value: any, body: any)
    {
        if (this.body[name] && !value) {
                delete this.body[name];
            } else {
                this.body[name] = { $in: value };
            }
    }

    private onFilterReceived(value: any, type: string, body)
    {
        if (type === 'lan')
        {
            this.processType('languages.primary', value, body);
        } if (type === 'zip')
        {
            this.processType('addresses.zipCode', value, body);
        } 

        this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body, this.sort)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.data = resRecordsData.data;
            if (this.filter === undefined)
            {
                this.data = resRecordsData.data;
            } else
            this.data.sort(this.filter);
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    }
```

All of the above works as expected.

However, as mentioned, I'd like to move the initial part of this logic to the service layer, and then just pass the result of that into the subscription in the component. So what I have tried (that's not working currently) is this:

In the service layer I have this:

```
public processType(name: string, value: any, body: any)
{
    if (this.body[name] && !value) {
            return delete this.body[name];
        } else {
            return this.body[name] = { $in: value };
        }
}

public getFilterInput(value, type, body)
{
    if (type === 'lan')
    {
        return this.processType('languages.primary', value, body);
    } if (type === 'zip')
    {
        return this.processType('addresses.zipCode', value, body);
    } 

}
```

Notice I'm returning values here, because from my understanding this is something I need to do when abstracting out to the service layer.

So then in the component I've refactored to this:

```
body: any = {'group': 'consulting'};

private processType(name, value, body)
{
    this.filtersService.processType(name, value, body);
}

private onFilterReceived(value: any, type: string, sort?)
{
    this.filtersService.getFilterInput(type, value);

    this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body, this.sort)
    .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        this.data = resRecordsData.data;
        if (this.filter === undefined)
        {
            this.data = resRecordsData.data;
        } else
        this.data.sort(this.filter);
    },
    responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

And at present I then get this error in the console:

> inline template:2:8 caused by: Cannot read property
>   'languages.primary' of undefined

What am I missing here? How do I need to handle this differently when moving this logic to the service layer?

EDIT: Made edits to my code (reflected above) to pass in "body". Still getting undefined error, however.

Answer (score 1):

`this.body[name]` body is unavailable in service that is the reason `langauges.primary` is undefined you need to pass in the body to the service

**UPDATE**

```
public processType(name: string, value: any, body: any)
{
    let body = body;
    if (body[name] && !value) {
            return delete body[name];
        } else {
            return body[name] = { $in: value };
        }
}
```

And then in the component, this:

```
private processType(name, value)
{
    let body = {'group': 'consulting'};
    this.filtersService.processType(name, value, body);
}
```

Comment: Right. I see your point. I have added my initial component value for "body" in the code above. So how would I pass that into the service layer? If I try initializing "body" to an empty object in the service layer, the error goes away but the functionality doesn't work. In other words, nothing happens when I click on the filter.

Comment: pass it along with the method or on `ngOnInit`. to the service save it to a variable there and use the same

Comment: Pass it within the "processType()" method, you mean?

Comment: That's the value that's passed to the API that allows for the filtering. It's a Mongo/Mongoose feature that let's you filter directly in the payload query.

Comment: can you try by passing  in the body

Comment: remove the `this` from that method it will be only body , `this` is used to refer to the component level variable, you need to use the passed body

Comment: Tried that. Back to my undefined error. See additional code above.

Comment: @Ademo you are doing it wrong Please c the update in answer

Comment: @Ademo sorry my bad instead of this.body use let if you have a body component var then use this.body . if you are still facing issues try and make a plunker for the same

Comment: Thanks for the help, thus far. I will pick this up in the morning with a refactored question. One note: in your code code you both have "body" as a passed in parameter and defined with "let". That errors out for me as a "duplicate identifier". I think I just need to include "body" as a parameter, but not include it within the function, since it is received from elsewhere in the component, where "body" is already defined.

Comment: ya that is waht i pointed if you already have a component level var dont use let body

Comment: Right. But then I'm back to my "undefined" error. Will give it another look in the morning with fresh eyes. Thanks for the input. I know it's close.